# Wordpress - 2 other sites in same theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got wordpress site with installed theme. I want to create 2 sites with same theme, just differs only subdomain and menu and index page (just specific "page" in wordpress). How to resolve this? Multisite in wordpress or some other simplest way (or maybe multisite is the simplest way to do this)?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the WordPress multisite feature, but here's a good reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.

> A multisite network is a collection of sites that all share the same
>   WordPress installation. They can also share plugins and themes. The
>   individual sites in the network are *virtual* sites in the sense that
>   they do not have their own directories on your server, although they
>   do have separate directories for media uploads within the shared
>   installation, and they do have separate tables in the database.

From this point of view, I think it is the simplest way of implementing the same theme in both sites. Also, if you install WordPress in two different folders of the same server it will be considerably slower than if you use multisite.